# calling stored procedure spring boot application using jparepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to call a stored procedure in SQL Server using Spring JPARepository, I followed exactly that is suggested in documentation but I get the error saying “Invalid mix of positional and named parameters” Below I have given all the classes and stored procedures I have used, when I do a filterCreatives(...) call on the JPARepository it fails with the said error,
and as you know if I make the return type of filterCreatives(..) void it passes now How can I make the code work with return type as List I have seen the same problem in stack overflow for a long time but it is unanswered

Please can you help me if there is a out of box solution tried searching in the net stood in vain thanks in advance.

**Stored Procedure in SQL Server:**

```
Alter Procedure filtercreatives
    /* Input Parameters */
    @category_id nvarchar(MAX),
    @advertiser_id nvarchar(MAX),
    @platform_id nvarchar(MAX),
    @size_id nvarchar(MAX),
    @template_id nvarchar(MAX),
    @language_id    nvarchar(MAX)

AS
   BEGIN
    /* Variable Declaration */
    Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
    Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar (2000)
    /* Build the Transact-SQL String with the input parameters */ 
    Set @SQLQuery = 'Select * From creativegallery_config where  ' 
    /* check for the condition AND build the WHERE clause accordingly */

                If (@category_id is not null AND @category_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + '  category_id in ('+@category_id+') AND'

   If (@advertiser_id is not null AND @advertiser_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' advertiser_id in ('+@advertiser_id+') AND'

    If (@platform_id is not null AND @platform_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' platform_id in ('+@platform_id+') AND'

    If (@size_id is not null AND @size_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' size_id in ('+@size_id+') AND'

                If (@template_id is not null AND @template_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' template_id in ('+@template_id+') AND'

                If (@language_id is not null AND @language_id != '') 
         Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' language_id in ('+@language_id+') '
                Set @SQLQuery = RTRIM(@SQLQuery)

                Declare @len as varchar(200)
                Set @len = LEN(@SQLQuery)
                if( CHARINDEX('DNA',REVERSE(@SQLQuery)) < 2 and CHARINDEX('DNA',REVERSE(@SQLQuery)) >0)
                                Set @SQLQuery = SUBSTRING(@SQLQuery,1,LEN(@SQLQuery)-3)
                if( CHARINDEX('EREHW',REVERSE(@SQLQuery)) < 2 and CHARINDEX('EREHW',REVERSE(@SQLQuery)) >0)
                                Set @SQLQuery = SUBSTRING(@SQLQuery,1,LEN(@SQLQuery)-5)

                  Execute sp_Executesql     @SQLQuery


    If @@ERROR <> 0 GoTo ErrorHandler
    Return(0)

ErrorHandler:
    Return(@@ERROR)
END
```

**Java entity class :**

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
           name="filtercreatives", 
           procedureName="filtercreatives", 
            parameters={
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@category_id"),
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@advertiser_id"),
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@platform_id"),
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@size_id"),
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@template_id"),
                     @StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class,name="@language_id")
           },resultClasses=CreativeConfig.class
       )
@Entity
@Table(name = "creativegallery_config")
public class CreativeConfig implements Serializable{
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 6201074363091569476L;
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Integer id;
       private Integer advertiserId;
       private Integer sizeId;
       private Integer languageId;
       private Integer platformId;
       private Integer templateId;
       private Integer categoryId;
       private String configUrl;
       private String tileImageUrl;


}
```

**JPA Repository Interface:**

```
@Repository
public interface CreativeConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<CreativeConfig, Integer> {

       List<CreativeConfig> findByAdvertiserIdIn(List<Integer> advertiserId);
       @Procedure(name = "filtercreatives")
       List<CreativeConfig> filterCreatives(@Param("@category_id")String categoryId,@Param("@advertiser_id") String advertiserId,@Param("@platform_id") String platformId,@Param("@size_id") String sizeId,
                     @Param("@template_id")String templateId, @Param("@language_id")String languageId
                     );
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid mix of named and positional parameters; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mix of named and positional parameters
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.ignitionone.config.WebSecurityConfig$1.doFilterInternal(WebSecurityConfig.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid mix of named and positional parameters; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mix of named and positional parameters
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.FilterCreatives(Unknown Source)
    at com.ignitionone.service.ConfigAdvertiserDBService.getConfigs(ConfigAdvertiserDBService.java:176)
    at com.ignitionone.service.ConfigAdvertiserDBService.getConfigs(ConfigAdvertiserDBService.java:154)
    at com.ignitionone.controller.CreativesController.getCreativess(CreativesController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mix of named and positional parameters
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getOutputParameterValue(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.extractOutputValue(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:298)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterStrategyException: Attempt to access positional parameter [7] but ProcedureCall using named parameters
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getParameterRegistration(ProcedureCallImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.getOutputParameterValue(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:276)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please share your stack trace of error

Comment: @Makoton the root cause of the issue is the stored procedure should send a data which can be casted to List<CreativeConfig> then it will find the output paramter (i.e position 7) I was not understanding how to configure the results of the executed query in stored procedure to be mapped to List<CreativeConfig> which is return value of JPARepository interface

Comment: To avoid the mix of positional and named parameters you can use the `outputParameterName` attribute of `@Procedure`. The default is `""` which falls back to the positional one using `parameters.size()+1` in the execution. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ChristophStrobl Please can you help me in tweaking the stored procedure above to use outputParameterName attribute since I did not find documentation to do so , the documentation provided by spring data show how to map sql data types only not resultsets

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question in another query. I can't find it now. But essentially, you need to remove the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery from your entity class and call the procedure directly in your service class:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

// your method structure here

StoredProcedureQuery query = em.CreateStoredProcedureQuery("filtercreatives", CreativeConfig.class);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(0, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
/*
 * repeat the above format for each parameter. Notice the use of
 * digits instead of parameter names. Then.....
 */
 query.setParameter(0,"your value");
```

As I side note, another 'gotcha' I found was that the returned parameters were given underscores, even if there were none, if camel-case was used. So, if you have problems with it not finding 'configUrl', and your database doesn't have 'config_url', try changing it in your code to 'configurl'.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue I got resolved by jus removing @ sign from
updated
**@StoredProcedureParameter(  mode=ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name="category_id")**